# Is there a difference between Dynatrace Managed and Dynatrace for Government?

Tags: dynatrace

When setting up SSO for my Dynatrace Managed install, I came across this page:
https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/manage/access-control/user-management-and-sso#dynatrace-for-government

which lists "Dynatrace Managed" and "Dynatrace for Government" separately. I thought the government would use a dynatrace managed install, is that incorrect? would they instead be using this "dynatrace for government"?

I thought dynatrace managed was supossed to be the de-facto on-premises install of dynatrace, as opposed to the SaaS version. Is that not the case?

I tried reading through https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/get-started/dynatrace-for-government but it's not exactly clear if it's meaning that "dynatrace for government" is a special product they sell, or if they're saying in general that dynatrace can be used in government environments because it meets FedRAMP requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Dynatrace for Government is the actual FedRAMP approved deployment of Dynatrace. Given that FedRAMP tackles Cloud Service offerings compliance, it would make sense that this means SaaS.

Dynatrace Managed likely doesn't require FedRAMP speciality approval to be used by government departments, as it's not a requirement to run that on cloud. I could be wrong.

I saw these links in the documentation:
For an overview of Dynatrace for Government, see Federal Government - Modernize your agency with automatic and intelligent observability: https://www.dynatrace.com/solutions/government/us-government/
To review Dynatrace FedRAMP authorization information, see Dynatrace FedRAMP profile: https://marketplace.fedramp.gov/#!/product/dynatrace-for-government?sort=productName